# Amazon EC2 instance has new IP, updated DNS records, still points to old IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

Long story short here, I restarted my EC2 instance unwittingly which (without an EIP) changed the pubic facing IP address.  Ok fair enough, but after I changed the DNS records on Hover.com for my domain now when I type in www.mydomain.com it points back to the old instance IP that doesn't work.

I verified this with `host www.mydomain.com` on my Linux command line.

I looked at the DNS records and they are clearly changed to the new IP for the A records (for * and @).

The only thing I can come up with is that perhaps the DNS servers listed are the problem.  Here are the name servers I'm using [image]
My attempted solution has been trying to find a way to update these servers, but I am not finding any help on that.  Any recommendations to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you clear the DNS cache on the client? To check that the DNS change was actually made, go to a third-party (like https://www.dnsqueries.com/en/dns_lookup.php) and ask it to resolve the name. If it's correct, but your client is not, then your client is probably using an old, cached entry.

Comment: @jarmod who are we referring to as the client in this instance?  pardon my ignorance

Comment: By client, I mean the computer that is still resolving the name to the old IP address. DNS caching sometimes happens on the client but it also happens elsewhere e.g. your ISP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the TTL (Time To Live = cache duration) on your DNS server, be sure to use the smallest duration allowed (0 if possible).  This will tell DNS relays and clients to cache the resolution for a short period of time (or not at all if you set it to 0)

However, [some clients](https://www.rexconsulting.net/tip-java-does-not-honor-dns-ttl-recommendation-in-enterprise-environment.html) do not honor the TLS proposed by the DNS and your only solution is to wait for their cache to expire.

The `dig` command will show you the TTL sent by your DNS server, as in the example below : 60 secs.

```sh
$ dig www.stormacq.com +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> www.stormacq.com +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.192.29.54
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.192.29.133
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.192.29.136
www.stormacq.com.   60  IN  A   54.192.29.234
```

I would suggest you to use an Elastic IP Address, these are provided without charges as long as it is attached to a running EC2 instance.  (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html for more details)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by using Hover's DNS servers instead of using Amazon's.  I contacted Hover and they recommended changing to their name servers and removing Amazon's.  Apparently Amazon's DNS servers were taking a long time to update records (if they were trying to at all).

- Record #1   ns1.hover.com
- Record #2   ns2.hover.com
- Record #3   blank
- Record #4   blank

*edit: Thumbs down but no comment explaining why?  This answer worked for me